# curve fitting with python

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some data and stuff, I know there is a simple command to do this with python/numpy/matplotlib, but I can't find it. I think it is something like

```
popt,popc = numpy.curvefit(f,x)
```

where `popt` is the paramters of `f`, `popc` is the fit quality and `f` is a predefined function of f. Does any of you know it?

Comment: If this is a one-off, it's easier to just plug the values into the function finder at http://zunzun.com/ and let it find the best matching curve.  Their Python code is available, too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Take a look at [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kw)
>
> Use non-linear least squares to fit a function, f, to data.

Comment: One question: is there an easy way to get R-squared value out of curve_fit, or get SSE so that I can calculate R-squared? I can do some work and get it done in scipy.optimize.leastsq, but the code will be much more verbose.

Answer (score -1):

[Found it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). Curve_fit from optimize in scipy

Comment: Isn't this answer a duplicate of the accepted answer?