# I don't understand what is wrong with my code - Pyplot gives me errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, curve-fitting

```
    import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log, e, ceil, floor,sqrt,pi,exp
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange,array, empty
import pdb
from random import randint
import copy
from operator import add 
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy


def walk(n):      
    time = 0   
    i = 0    
    while i < n:
        if i == 0:    
            r = random.random()   
            t = -log(1-r,e)    
            time = time+t 
            i=i+1
        
        elif i !=0 and i!=n-1 :  
            r_2 = random.random()
            t_2 = -log(1-r_2,e)
            time = time+t_2
            
            R = random.random()   
            if 0 <= R < 0.5:     
                i = i -1    
            elif 0.5 <= R <=1:
                i=i+1     
        else:   
            i = n
    return time



def many_walks(n,m):       
    v_t = []    
    for i in range(m):
        w = walk(n)
        v_t.append(w)
    
    return v_t    
        
n = 20
m = 2000     
bins =  [10*i for i in range(200)]    
numpy_hist = plt.figure()        
plt.hist(many_walks(n,m), bins)

def func(x,s):
     x = np.array(x)
     return (4/(x*np.sqrt(np.pi*n*s)))*np.exp(-(np.log(x)**2)/(2*n*s))

xx = np.linspace(0.1,2000,10000)



    
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, bins, many_walks(n,m))
```

Without you reading too much, basically the function "many_walks(n,m)" gives me a vector containing m numbers. I've used matplotlib to plot a histogram and it works.

Now I want to consider the function which I defined as func(x,s). Notice it also has a parameter, which is n (yes, the same n of walks and many_walks). I would like to fit this  function to my histogram, so I tried similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887099/python-curve-fitting-on-a-barplot) but it doesn't work. I mean I'm very suck I don't understand what I am doing wrong, seems I'm doing the same as in the question posted. My aim is to be able to find the coefficient s such that the function is fitted on the histogram and plot it on the same plot.

here's the error that it is giving me

> ```
> return (4/(x*np.sqrt(np.pi*n*s)))*np.exp(-(np.log(x,e)**2)/(2*n*s))
> ```
>
> TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

Comment: There are too many errors here to give you a solution. 1. `np.log(x,e)` makes no sense. 2. `x` needs to be a numpy array for this function to work. 3. most importantly, you will never be able to fit this function to the data, independent of the variable `s`. Try to find a new fitting function, which would actually allow to fit the data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I'll improve it, sorry my Python skills are very limited. For 1, I will check the documentation. For 2, is there a way I can change my definition of func for it to work? And for 3, how do you know I'll never be able to fit this fuction?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've substituted np.log(x,e) with np.log(x) now. The error I'm receiving is "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,) (2000,)" on the line "return func(xdata, *params) - ydata".

Comment: 2. put `x = np.array(x)` into the func definition. 3. The function is normalized, your data is not normalized. It's as easy as that. You can also plot the function for different `s` and observe how it behaves.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, number 4., of course `bins` must have the same number of elements as the array returned by `many_walks(n,m)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for 2. I've just added it in the definition, hopefully that is what you meant. As normalized you mean that the mean is zero? There should be a mean parameter (cause that should be a lognormal distribution) however I just put it to zero to try it simpler. If I add the mean parameter, should it work then?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'll also try to plot it for different s's thank you. And about 4, I am not sure I understand. Normally when we do histograms the bins are "containers" of the x's and so there should be less bins than actual x values, right? For example I put the bins every 10 integers so that they would contain more than one data

Comment: Yes, for the histogram you need some low number of bins. But for fitting x and y must have the same number of elements. So, you may not want to put the return array of `many_walks(n,m)` into the fit, but the histogrammed data instead. Maybe you want to do one step back, use an easier function like to normal gaussian distribution, sample from it and try to fit it. Once that works, you can look again at more complicated cases.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry I'm so confused.. is it okay if I move this to chat? I'd like to understand better because I think there is just so much I don't know about programming and python in general that is making my life very hard I think..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136897/discussion-between-euler-salter-and-importanceofbeingernest).